# Фиксирование перенос строки JS

Tags: javascript, перенос

Хотелось бы узнать, как в textarea проверять, стоит ли перенос строки, к примеру

```
if(textarea.value == "перенос"){
    textarea.value += "br"
}
```

И после того как жмешь на кнопку вывести (к примеру есть такая кнопка), то он в 
местах где перенос, вставлял "br" или "p" (теги)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариант с помощью замены `\n` на `<br />`

```js
button.onclick = () => {
    output.innerHTML = textarea.value.replace(/\n/g, '<br />');
};
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
<button id="button">Отобразить</button>
<p id="output"></p>
```

---

Вариант с помощью `CSS` `white-space: pre-line;`

```js
textarea.oninput = (e) => (output.innerHTML = e.target.value);
```

```css
p {
    white-space: pre-line;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
<p id="output"></p>
```

---

Ваш вариант с помощью стоп слова.

```js
textarea.oninput = (e) => {
    output.innerHTML = e.target.value.replace(/перенос/g, '<br />');
};
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
<p id="output"></p>
```

Comment: не понял только как сделать не на oninput, а на нажатие, то есть чтобы после нажатия он выводил, а не во время ввода (onclick)

Comment: @klausdartant в первом примере оставил отображение с помощью кнопки

Comment: пропустил, спасибо большое, давно искал как делать пробел, никак не мог понять как фиксировать перенос, думал что надо либо \n использовать, либо html символы (&times и т.п)

Answer (score 2):

При нажатии **enter**, в значение **textarea** добавляется символ переноса строки. Это поведение по-умолчанию. Для вывода в HTML, переносы надо заменять на br.

```
value.replace(/\n/g, '<br/>');
```

Иначе переносы будут заменены пробелами.

Comment: можешь пожалуйста показать пример в коде, буду очень благодарен